# Signing pdf document with crypto in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, multer

I am sending from frontend one pdf file and stored in nodejs side correctly thanks to Multer.

I have one function with this content:

```
async function signDocument ( req, res ) {
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync ( './config/privateKey.pem', 'utf-8' ),
        publicKey  = fs.readFileSync ( './config/publicKey.pem', 'utf-8' ),
        file       = fs.readFileSync ( req.file.path, 'utf-8' ),
        signer     = crypto.createSign ( 'sha256' )

  signer.update ( file )
  signer.end ()

  const signature  = signer.sign ( privateKey ),
        signature_hex = signature.toString('hex'),
        verifier   = crypto.createVerify ( 'sha256' )

  verifier.update ( file )
  verifier.end ()
  const verified = verifier.verify ( publicKey, signature )
  console.log ( JSON.stringify ( {
    signature : signature_hex,
    verified
  }, null, 2 ) )
}
```

next step, I open file saved correctly in the folder specified but the pdf file is not appearing as signed in acrobat reader (for example)

Any help with this code it is not throwing errors but it is not working ..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code creates simple PKCS #1 signature. You need to create PAdES or PKCS #7 signature and insert it into the PDF as well.
See this module that will help you further https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf

How does this code work? Its from the library test suite https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf/blob/master/src/signpdf.test.js

If you save the Buffer into new PDF file then you should see the digital signature when opening with Adobe.

```
it('signs a ready pdf containing a link', async () => {
    const p12Buffer = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../resources/certificate.p12`);
    let pdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../resources/including-a-link.pdf`);
    pdfBuffer = plainAddPlaceholder({
        pdfBuffer,
        reason: 'I have reviewed it.',
        location: 'some city',
        signatureLength: 1612,
    });
    pdfBuffer = signer.sign(pdfBuffer, p12Buffer);

    const {signature, signedData} = extractSignature(pdfBuffer);
    expect(typeof signature === 'string').toBe(true);
    expect(signedData instanceof Buffer).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I tried to work with this module but it is not recognizing sign function. On the other hand, do you think is a responsibility of frontend side or backend?

Comment: Signature creation and embedding into the PDF is definitely backend task. As the whole PDF signing process is quite big undertaking then I might be able to help when digging deeper into the project. You can get in touch with me using the email in my profile.